# JobService rescheduling

Tags: android, jobservice

What I wonder is if the `JobParameters` sent in `jobFinished` are the ones passed on to `onStartJob` when a `JobService` is restarted?

Say I start a thread in my `JobService` and in it I call `jobFinished` with true as the `needsReschedule` parameter. If I have added something new to the `JobParameters` extras that are also given to `jobFinished`, will this be visible when eventually `onStartJob` is called again? or will `onStartJob` always only provide the `JobParameters` that were provided when the service was initially started?

Comment: What about trying?

Comment: Of course you can always just test your way into working code, but in my experience you get a less buggy result if you know from the beginning how the functions you use work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and it turns out that the `PersistableBundle` in the `onStartJob` function will always be the one sent initially, so changing any data and sending it in `jobFinished` won't work.